# Composing several functions using a compose utility

Tags: javascript, composition

I am supposed to create a function that takes some functions as arguments, and returns a composition of those arguments in the following way:
Given functions fnN, fn(N-1), ..., fn1, and a value v, the function should return the result of

```
compose(fnN, fnN-1, ..., fn1)(v) = fnN(fnN-1(...(fn1(v))));
```

I would be grateful if someone can help out and answer why this method doesn't:

```
function compose(...fns) { 
  return function composed(v) {
    if (fns.length >= 2) {
      return fns[0](compose(...fns.slice(1)));
    } else return fns[0](v);
  }
}
```

Thank you!

I know that this solution works for example:

```
function compose(...fns) {
  return function(v) {
    for (let fn of fns) {
      v = fn(v);
    }
    return v;
  }
}
```

Comment: You're never calling the result of the recursive call on `v`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix you recursive call to call the resulting function with a given argument.

```js
function compose(...fns) { 
  return function composed(v) {
    const [first, ...rest] = fns;
    if (!rest.length) return first(v)
    
    return first(compose(...rest)(v))
  }
}


function inc(x) { return x + 1 }


console.log(compose(inc, inc, inc)(0))
```

Comment: You flipped the execution order from first-to-last to last-to-first. Try with my example functions, inc, double, third, with the testing value of `2`.

Comment: I was following the OPs code that was not clear.